# Issues with Tails and a high dpi screen

Tags: tails

I am booting from Tails using a usb.  I can start up the machine fine, but everything looks very small.  My resolution is 2880x1800 with a dpi of 220, but it is detected as 2880x1800 with a dpi of 94.

I have tried using xrandr to change the dpi but it fails to cause anything to happen visually.

Additionally, I have tried to just change the resolution to something smaller; using the system tools options in the menu and using xrandr, but both of those result in a black screen.

Comment: Sounds like you should file this on their bugtracker?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to have been submitted to the Tails' bug tracker and seems to have been already resolved.

You can have a look here:
https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/8659